# How can I use SQL to get a variable value from a literal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

Part 1

```
DECLARE @A INT
DECLARE @B NVARCHAR(20)

SET @A=123
SET @B='@A'
```

Part 2

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL='SELECT ' + @B

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
--Should return 123
```

**Directly referencing @A in non-dynamic SQL would not be acceptable for this task.**

The above in Part 2 is generically what I am trying to do. I understand the variable is out of scope and it won't work as done above. How could I use @B to get the value of @A?

**UPDATE 20190322**:
I actually forgot about this question and implemented logging on the C# side instead of the database, but I got curious again if this was possible. Again, this needs to be generic as I would want to put it into the tops of any stored procedure and I do not want to customize it per sproc; I'm having trouble in the cursor getting the value of a parameter. Here is a working example:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO    

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoggingTest]
    @DateBegin datetime,
    @DateEnd datetime,
    @Person varchar(8000),
    @Unit varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    --BEGIN LOGGING CODE
    DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @Parameter_name nvarchar(2000), @type nvarchar(50), @length SMALLINT, @Prec SMALLINT, @Scale SMALLINT, @Param_order SMALLINT, @Collation nvarchar(2000);  
    DECLARE param_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        SELECT
           'Parameter_name' = name,  
           'Type'   = type_name(user_type_id),  
           'Length'   = max_length,  
           'Prec'   = case when type_name(system_type_id) = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                      then precision  
                      else OdbcPrec(system_type_id, max_length, precision) end,  
           'Scale'   = OdbcScale(system_type_id, scale),  
           'Param_order'  = parameter_id,  
           'Collation'   = convert(sysname, 
                           case when system_type_id in (35, 99, 167, 175, 231, 239)  
                           then ServerProperty('collation') end)  
        from sys.parameters
        where object_id = object_id(OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID))

    OPEN param_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM param_cursor   
    INTO @Parameter_name,@type,@length,@Prec,@Scale,@Param_order,@Collation

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        SET @String=@String + @Parameter_name + '==' --+ SELECT @Parameter_name --This is part I can't think of a way to do; need to record/capture the value

        SET @String=@String + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        FETCH NEXT FROM param_cursor   
        INTO @Parameter_name, @type,@length,@Prec,@Scale,@Param_order,@Collation
    END   
    CLOSE param_cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE param_cursor;

    --INSERT DATA INTO LOG TABLE HERE
    SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) AS [ProcedureName],@String AS [Data],GETDATE() AS [LogTime]
    --END LOGGING CODE    

    /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        DO BUSINESS STUFF HERE!
        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
    /*
    BLAH
    BLAH
    BLAH

        DECLARE @Now DATETIME=GETDATE()
        EXEC [dbo].[LoggingTest] @Now,@Now,'Person Value','Unit Value'
    */
END
GO
```

Comment: What is the context that you would be exectuing these two pieces of code?  And how would they be connected to each other?

Comment: This is a generic version of a more complicated task I'm working on. I'm trying to make a generic bit of SQL code that I can put at the top of a sproc that will log information (sproc name, parameters, and parameter values). I hit a snag when trying to get the parameter values. I know the names of the parameters, but I need to query them dynamically

Comment: I've done this more than once and AFAIK the only workable way is to explicitly pass in the parameters.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Hehe, I certainly know that route is open, but if there is a way to not have to code each sproc in a custom manner, that would be lovely.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid knowing the data type of @A, or knowing the name of @A at all?

Comment: I know the variable's name because it's value is in @B. I can't use static SQL to get the value however because that would defeat the purpose of what I'm working on.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure that there is no workable way to do this in T-SQL code.  OTOH, Profiler/Trace can already do most of this for you (though I don't think that there's an effective way to get the parameter values).

Comment: @RBarryYoung that is what I was thinking too, but there are so many people here, that I figured it would be worth a post

Comment: Well, I'd be happy to be wrong, *BUT*, a couple of years ago I wrote a HIPPA DB Logger for a customer and I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the same thing: how could I add a single unmodified command/statement to the beginning of every sproc that could log the full invocation context, *including the parameters*.  And I couldn't find a way to do it without explicitly passing the parameters (which is what I ended up doing).

Comment: I think you are striving for one too many layers of abstraction.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to petition Microsoft to add a GetValueByName function.  :)

Comment: @SpectralGhost I might be convinced to agree if I understood your use case. To me it sounds like you just don't want to bother writing code with meaningful variable names and data types. One procedure to do everything?

Comment: My use case is in the second comment. I'm trying to write a generic logging mechanism in SQL. I have everything done that I would need except for grabbing the values of the sproc parameters. I'll post a SQL Fiddle here in a moment if that helps

Comment: In that comment you said that you know the names of the parameters, but then you said you can't use the parameter names, so I'm sorry if I'm confused. Obfuscating what you're doing can often be useful for simplification, but you can go too far too...

Comment: SQL Fiddle for context: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8856/1/0

Comment: There seems to be no direct/easy way (at least I can;'t find one), but would a detour that makes your `LoggingTest` work as expected satisfy?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I’m not sure what you mean by detour

Comment: It has been asked before on dba.se [Is there any way to access the variables in a dynamic sql which is declared outside the dynamic sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84315/57105). The answer is "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around, I found that one can

1. Have the running procedure code from `dm_exec_requests` & `dm_exec_sql_text`
2. Have the procedure call from `dm_exec_input_buffer`. I should note that I am not very proficient in this, and I think I read somewhere it does not work on queries done outside SSMS....
3. As already seen in your code, the parameters can be found in `sys.parameters`

Thus, I implemented a way to do this. Main algorithm steps are:

> 1. Create a dummy proc with same params and default values. Change its body to a single `SELECT`. By using a dynamic xml-concatenation of the parameters at the original proc which is one level higher, we can provide the dummy proc a `VALUES` table which includes both the parameter names (in quotes) and their values(no quotes).
> 2. Exec the dummy proc by using the same call parameters used in the original spc. `INSERT` the `EXEC` result-set into a temp table. Drop the dummy proc
>      afterwards.

Now we have a temp table with both parameter names AND values.

Most of the new code is before yours starts, except from the actual value you need in the cursor. Also, to avoid furious parsing, I used a (cheap) trick of adding a comment `--postBeginParserMarker` just after  the `BEGIN` so that I know where the proc begins...

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoggingTest]
    @DateBegin datetime,
    @DateEnd datetime,
    @Person varchar(8000),
    @Unit varchar(8000)='someunithere'
AS
BEGIN --postBeginParserMarker
    declare @SPID int= @@SPID;
    declare @request_id int;
    declare @dummyspc nvarchar(max)
    select @dummyspc = 'spc_dummy_'+ convert(nvarchar,max(object_id)+1) from sys.procedures -- just a way to ensure no conflicts between simultaneous runs of this very proc
    --select @dummyspc

    declare @thisprocname sysname
    select @thisprocname=o.name,@request_id=request_id
    from sys.dm_exec_requests r
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) t
    inner join sys.objects o on t.objectid=o.object_id
    where r.session_id=@SPID
    --select @thisprocname

    declare @newproc nvarchar(max)
    SELECT @newproc=substring(st.text,1,CHARINDEX ('--postBeginParserMarker' , st.text)-1 )
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) st
    where r.session_id=@SPID
    set @newproc=replace(@newproc,@thisprocname,@dummyspc)

    SELECT @newproc+=
         char(13)+char(10)
        +'select * from ( values'
        +STUFF
        (
            (    
                SELECT char(13)+char(10)+char(9)+',('+convert(nvarchar,parameter_id)+','''+name+''',convert(nvarchar,'+name+'))'
                from sys.parameters 
                where object_id=object_id(@thisprocname)
                FOR XML PATH('') , TYPE
            ).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
            , 4, 1, ' ' 
        )
        +char(13)+char(10)+')t(parameter_id,parameter_name,parameter_value)'
        +char(13)+char(10)+'END'
    --select @newproc

    declare @newproccall nvarchar(max)
    select @newproccall=event_info from sys.dm_exec_input_buffer ( @SPID ,@request_id)
    set @newproccall=replace(@newproccall,@thisprocname,@dummyspc)
    --select @newproccall

    exec(@newproc)

    if object_id('tempdb..#paramtbl') is not null drop table #paramtbl
    create table #paramtbl (parameter_id int,parameter_name nvarchar(max),parameter_value nvarchar(max))
    insert #paramtbl(parameter_id,parameter_name,parameter_value)
    exec(@newproccall)

    -- select * from #paramtbl  <-- Now this has all you need

    exec('drop procedure '+@dummyspc)

    --BEGIN LOGGING CODE
    DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @Parameter_name nvarchar(2000), @type nvarchar(50), @length SMALLINT, @Prec SMALLINT, @Scale SMALLINT, @Param_order SMALLINT, @Collation nvarchar(2000);  

    --select @Unit as val
    --drop table ##a 
    --select @@SPID


    DECLARE param_cursor CURSOR FOR   
        SELECT
           'Parameter_name' = name,  
           'Type'   = type_name(user_type_id),  
           'Length'   = max_length,  
           'Prec'   = case when type_name(system_type_id) = 'uniqueidentifier' 
                      then precision  
                      else OdbcPrec(system_type_id, max_length, precision) end,  
           'Scale'   = OdbcScale(system_type_id, scale),  
           'Param_order'  = parameter_id,  
           'Collation'   = convert(sysname, 
                           case when system_type_id in (35, 99, 167, 175, 231, 239)  
                           then ServerProperty('collation') end)  
        from sys.parameters
        where object_id = object_id('LoggingTest')

    OPEN param_cursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM param_cursor   
    INTO @Parameter_name,@type,@length,@Prec,@Scale,@Param_order,@Collation

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        SET @String=@String + @Parameter_name + '==' + (SELECT isnull(parameter_value,'<NULL>') from #paramtbl where parameter_id=@Param_order)

        SET @String=@String + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        FETCH NEXT FROM param_cursor   
        INTO @Parameter_name, @type,@length,@Prec,@Scale,@Param_order,@Collation
    END   
    CLOSE param_cursor;  
    DEALLOCATE param_cursor;

    --INSERT DATA INTO LOG TABLE HERE
    SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID) AS [ProcedureName],@String AS [Data],GETDATE() AS [LogTime]
    --END LOGGING CODE    

    /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        DO BUSINESS STUFF HERE!
        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
    /*
    BLAH
    BLAH
    BLAH

        DECLARE @Now DATETIME=GETDATE()
        EXEC [dbo].[LoggingTest] @Now,@Now,'Person Value','Unit Value'
    */
END
GO
```

Comment: Couple of very minor issues. This is a bit lengthy, but working wonderfully.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, does it work when the SP is called from C#? (using RPC) In this case `select @newproccall=event_info from sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` should return only the name of the SP without any parameters. I don't see how `exec(@newproccall)` is getting parameters. It should fail with `Procedure or function ... expects parameter ..., which was not supplied.` Am I missing something?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I had not tested against c#, but it works perfectly fine for me in SSMS

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean, please let us know how it works in C#. Or any other environment where you call the SP **not** by sending an explicit `EXEC Proc @P1=123, @P2='qwerty'` to the server.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov You are correct. As you expected, this fails with an error when called from C# as a parameterized call.

Comment: Bit late, but I noticed on the documentation that you need `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions to access `dm_exec_input_buffer`. The error could probably stem from there.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't understand the whole thing you are asking, but you can define the variables on `sp_executesql`:

```
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@A INT', @A = @A
```

Comment: Can't directly use @A in static SQL. I added a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

Though you don't have to do this, but still here is the way:

```
SET @B=@A
```

And you can directly assign value of @A:

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
 SET @SQL='SELECT ' + Convert(varchar(50),@A)
```

Comment: Can't directly use @A in static SQL. I added a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from SQL Server 2014 SP2 there is a [`sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) dynamic management view.

In previous versions there is [`DBCC INPUTBUFFER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-inputbuffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

It returns a table, which contains a column `event_info`, which contains "The text of the statement in the input buffer for the given spid."

So, you can add a simple query to the start of your stored procedure, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO LoggingTable(event_info, event_type, parameters)
SELECT
    InBuf.event_info
    ,InBuf.event_type
    ,InBuf.parameters
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_requests AS Req
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS Ses ON Ses.session_id = Req.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(Req.session_id, Req.request_id) AS InBuf
WHERE
    Ses.session_id > 50 
    AND Ses.is_user_process = 1
;
```

If you call/run your stored procedure using `EXEC`, such as

```
EXEC [dbo].[LoggingTest]
@DateBegin = '2019-01-01',
@DateEnd = '2020-01-01',
@Person = 'person name',
@Unit = 'some unit';
```

Then, `event_info` will contain this exact text of the `EXEC` query. I mean, exactly this text above. `EXEC [dbo].[LoggingTest] @DateBegin = '2019-01-01', @DateEnd = '2020-01-01',    @Person = 'person name', @Unit = 'some unit';` Obviously, it contains values of parameters and there is no need to parse anything or do any other tricks. It is enough for logging.

Cool. Event type will be "Language Event".

Unfortunately, if you call your stored procedure "properly" using RPC, which usually happens in, say, C# code, then all you'll get is just the name of the stored procedure in 
the `event_info`. Something like this:

```
YourDatabaseName.dbo.LoggingTest
```

There will be no mentioning of parameters and/or their values :-( Event type will be "RPC Event".

The `parameters` column is `smallint` and always contained `0` in my tests. Docs are not clear on how to make sense of this.

Comment: Runs, but given the example usage in the commented code I provided, it doesn't show the variable values. I'd say this is a partial solution.